# JavaScript não funciona no Safari/Edge?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Recentemente pedi orientação aqui no *SO* solicitando ajuda pra fazer um [cronometro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305733/cronometro-regressivo-esta-trazendo-o-valor-errado/305735#305735) via JavaScript.

Ao acessar em outros browser (Edge e Safari(versão Windows e Mac)) vi que o mesmo fica aparecendo desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E acessando nos demais Browser, carrega normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida é existe algum tratamento especial para o Broser "entender" *JavaScript* ?

```js
function Cronometro(dtFinal, ciclo) {
   var d, m, a;
   var dtF = dtFinal.replace("/", " ").replace("/", " ");
   dtF = dtF.split(" ");
   d = dtF[0];
   m = dtF[1];
   a = dtF[2];
   var countDownDate = new Date(m+" "+d+","+a).getTime();

   // Update the count down every 1 second
   var x = setInterval(function () {

       // Get todays date and time
       var now = new Date().getTime();

       // Find the distance between now an the count down date
       var distance = countDownDate - now;

       // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
       var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
       var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
       var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
       var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

       // Output the result in an element with id="demo"

       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Faltam " + days + " Dias " + hours + " Horas "
           + minutes + " Minutos para o fechamento da Semana " + ciclo;

       //If the count down is over, write some text 
       if (distance < 0) {
           clearInterval(x);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       }
   }, 1000);

}
        
Cronometro("30/06/2018", "14/2018");
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os browsers têm variações em relação aos formatos de data que conseguem interpretar. O código que você linkou usa o seguinte:

```
var countDownDate = new Date(m+" "+d+","+a).getTime();
```

Esse formato não é muito usual é não segue os padrões estabelecidos (uma [variação do ISO 8601 estendido](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)). Pode-se dizer que funcionou em alguns browsers por sorte. Para corrigir, sugiro usar outra forma do construtor `Date`, passando ano, mês e dia separadamente, nesta ordem, em vez de string.

```
var countDownDate = new Date(a, m-1, d).getTime();
```

> **Nota**
>   A documentação da MDN afirma que [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) aceita o formato de datas da RFC2822 (que é sobre formato de mensagens de email), ou seja, datas como `Aug 12, 2018`. De fato os engines de javascript costumam mesmo aceitar esse formato, porém vale alertar que ele não é citado na especificação da linguagem (ECMA-262). O mais seguro seria evitar.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente esses navegadores que você citou não reconhece o formato numérico do mês na data, tipo `"06 15, 2018"`. Teria que ser `"Jun 15, 2018"`.

**[Esta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** indica que o formato em string é válido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso você pode converter o número referente ao mês pela abreviação do nome do mês (ex.: Junho = Jun).

Pode usar uma array para pegar o respectivo nome, alterando o valor de `m`:

```
m = meses[parseInt(dtF[1])-1];
// parseInt para retirar o "0" do número do mês (06 => 6)
// o -1 para pegar o elemento no índice correto da array
```

**Veja funcionando:**

**Print Edge**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Print Safari**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var meses = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

function Cronometro(dtFinal, ciclo) {
   var d, m, a;
   var dtF = dtFinal.replace("/", " ").replace("/", " ");
   dtF = dtF.split(" ");
   d = dtF[0];
   m = meses[parseInt(dtF[1])-1];
   a = dtF[2];

   var countDownDate = new Date(m+" "+d+","+a).getTime();

   // Update the count down every 1 second
   var x = setInterval(function () {

       // Get todays date and time
       var now = new Date().getTime();

       // Find the distance between now an the count down date
       var distance = countDownDate - now;

       // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
       var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
       var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
       var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
       var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
       

       // Output the result in an element with id="demo"

       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Faltam " + days + " Dias " + hours + " Horas "
           + minutes + " Minutos para o fechamento da Semana " + ciclo;

       //If the count down is over, write some text 
       if (distance < 0) {
           clearInterval(x);
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       }
   }, 1000);

}
        
Cronometro("15/06/2018", "14/2018");
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Na verdade a documentação coloca isso como exemplo de *parsing non–standard date strings*. E *non-standard* é definido como o que não adere aos padrões que eu citei na minha resposta.

Comment: Parece que a MDN se embanana um pouco com isso mesmo. Enfim, browsers aceitam esse formato mas segundo a especificação mesmo eles não são padrões. Veja a atualização na minha resposta. De qualquer maneira eu não entendo no seu código por que transformar `15/06/2018` pra esse formato em vez de quebrar essa string e jogar as partes no construtor como eu sugeri. Não seria mais simples?

Comment: Sim, sua resposta é bem mais simples, com certeza.